# Function with union type as argument accepts object which is combination of two types

Tags: typescript

Here I get an error which I understand

```
interface Animal {
  name:string
}

interface Human{
  firstName:string
}

let test = (param: Animal )=>{
  if("name" in param)
   return param.name

  return param.firstName
}

console.log(test({name:"1", firstName:"2"}))
```

because `Animal` doesn't have `firstName`.

As soon as I modify that function to

```
let test = (param: Animal | Human)=>{
  if("name" in param)
   return param.name

  return param.firstName
}
```

the error is gone.
But I am confused. Doesn't `|` mean that the `param` is **either** `Animal` **or** `Human`?
But `{name:"1", firstName:"2"}` is neither isn't it? (Like in the first example TS wasn't accepting this as an `Animal`).

---

Bonus question also from the docs it says here it is not an error

```
    interface Pet {
      name: string;
    }
    let pet: Pet;
    // dog's inferred type is { name: string; owner: string; }
    let dog = { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" };
    pet = dog;
```

because `dog` has more properties  than a `Pet`. But why did it complain in my *initial* case when I passed the object as `Animal`? it had more properties, isn't it?

Comment: Object types aren't closed, so `{name: string, firstName: string}` is both an `Animal` and a `Hunan`.  Unions aren't exclusive, so `Animal & Human` is assignable to `Animal | Human` (but not vice versa).  See the answer to the linked question for more information.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

Your object `{name:"1", firstName:"2"}` does conform the union of your 2 interface.

The behaviour you are observing is called [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: I looked at your link but this answer is not clear to me. What is the union of your 2 interface? Isn't it *either* one or another interface? Can you add explanation? (Also please have a look at the updated bonus question).

Comment: @john That's [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) !